# Replace all instances of substring except at beginning of string

Tags: python, regex

I'm processing a load of poorly capitalized station names for a transit system, and want to de-capitalize words like "at" and "the". So far, I can match all instances I want to, except that I can't figure out how to *not* match instances occurring at the beginning of the string. (i.e. to prevent changing "The Thing" to "the Thing")

Here's my code so far:

```
>>>re.sub("(?i)(?<!\w)the(?!\w)", "zzz", "The Thing To The Theme of Athens, (The) Goethe")
'zzz Thing To zzz Theme of Athens, (zzz) Goethe'
```

And he's my current workaround:

```
>>>re.sub("(?i)(?<![\w|])the(?!\w)", "zzz", "|" + "The Thing To The Theme of Athens, (The) Goethe")[1:]
'The Thing To zzz Theme of Athens, (zzz) Goethe'
```

This workaround is obviously not ideal, as I'd prefer to have a "purely" regex solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace the negative lookbehind with a positive one changing `\w` with `\W`:

```
(?i)(?<=\W)the(?!\w)
    ^^^^^^^
```

The `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind can be presented as `(?<=^|\W)` (not working in Python, BTW), and we just need to take the `^` alternative out of it. The `(?<=\W)` positive lookbehind *requires* a non-word char immediately to the left of `t`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ur1rl7/1).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/VDD4We):

```
import re
res = re.sub(r"(?i)(?<=\W)the(?!\w)", "zzz", "The Thing To (The) Theme of Athens, The Goethe")
print(res) # => The Thing To (zzz) Theme of Athens, zzz Goethe
```

Comment: That was quick. Thanks!